# How to split lines in Zen Coding for vim

Tags: vim, emmet

Whenever I use Zen Coding for vim I usually have the same issue: When I want to wrap a paragraph with `p` the output would look like this:

```
<p>Text</p>
```

However, I'd like it to output like this:

```
<p>
     Text
</p>
```

How do I tell the zencoding plugin to split the output onto several lines?

Comment: I wanted to like zen coding but its default behavior, like in your example, irked me. For that use case, I much prefer the surround plugin: it can be used in any filetype, it satisfies my needs and expectations and it doesn't require committing to memory hundreds of shortcuts like zen coding does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In official Zen Coding (your Vim plugin has unofficial implementation, but it tries to stick close to it), you need to apply `xml` filter to your abbreviation. It will apply XML profile with different formatting options.

So, in your case, you may try to wrap text with `p|xml` abbreviation.

For further information on output tweaking, you may want to read the following:

- http://docs.emmet.io/customization/syntax-profiles/
- http://docs.emmet.io/filters/